# Remove Names from a text

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner, I have a text(type str) from which I have to remove all the names. I got this website: http://timmcnamara.co.nz/post/2650550090/extracting-names-with-6-lines-of-python-code

However, I am unable to run it in spyder (python version 3.4); it shows me error Please help me.

I'm getting this error.

```
 resource_val = pickle.load(opened_resource)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete and verifiable example. If you are getting an error, post the associated stack trace.

Comment: The code on the website you're following uses Python 2, which is not compatible with Python 3.4